# Get objects from an object array

Tags: javascript

If I have an array that looks like this;

```
markers[56] = { label: "One" };
markers[62] = { label: "Two" };
markers[87] = { label: "Three" };
markers[125] = { label: "Four" };
```

Now I have some JS;

```
for (var thisMarker in markers) {
  //What goes here so I can access the "label" property?
}
```

I know this is simplistic but later on there will be many more properties added to the object not just "label".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can access it like this,

```
for (var thisMarker in markers) {
  alert(markers[thisMarker].label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var thisMarker in markers){
//this will give you the label-     markers[thisMarker].label 
}
```